# IIS Query on starting file

Tags: iis

I am new to IIS and trying to understand when a website is setup in IIS what different folders are meant for and how to find out which file would be picked up first when a user woukd type URL of my site (say www.checkaccess.com)

Thanks

Comment: What version of IIS are you using as there are more than a handful out there?  There may be a "Default Document" tab in the website's properties if you are using IIS 6.0 or lower.  I'm not sure I understand what the question is in the first sentence as depending on what you put on the server, that software may create many folders as part of its install, e.g. some admin packages may have a /myappadmin folder possibly.

Comment: It is IIS 5.1 and I am deploying classic ASP website

Answer (score 1):

For IIS 5, open the IIS snap-in, right-click on any folder and choose Properties. Click on the Document tab. There is a checkbox there, "Enable Default Document" with a list of file names that IIS will try in turn for that directory.

Comment: Thanks, would this be any different if it was a .Net project

Comment: It is the space if it was an ASP.Net project, as there are other kinds of .Net projects outside of the web world.